# Axios network error only when using device

Tags: node.js, express, axios, expo, cors

I'm building an expo project with react native and I'm getting [AxiosError: Network Error] when I'm trying to sign up to my app with my iOS device. The error doesn't occur when using simulator or with postman, but only when I scan QR-code and try it with my device. I have tried using CORS in different ways but it hasn't helped. Is this common error with simple solution please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Network settings and set your network profile to Private. If your network is on public it wont be visible to other devices. On private network it trusts your network. Settings>>Network & Internet>>Properties.[image: Settings>>Network & Internet>>Properties]

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34434246)